# What is the proper way to serve iCal Events?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, icalendar

I am attempting to allow users to add events from an online calendar to the calendars on their device using [DDay.iCal](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DDay.iCal/). This seems to work fine on iOS and on desktop platforms, but I am running into a snag with Android devices. I run into this message:

[image: Android Error Message]

Is there a better way to serve this event that would keep that from happening?

```
public ActionResult ICS(int id)
{
        // Get event from Database
        var heEvent = HEEvent.GetEventDetails(id);

        // Create iCal object
        var iCal = new iCalendar();
        iCal.Method = "PUBLISH";

        // Create iCal Event
        var icalEvent = iCal.Create<DDay.iCal.Event>();
        icalEvent.Summary = heEvent.Name;
        icalEvent.Start = new iCalDateTime(heEvent.TimeBegin.Year, heEvent.TimeBegin.Month, heEvent.TimeBegin.Day, heEvent.TimeBegin.Hour, heEvent.TimeBegin.Minute, 00);

        TimeSpan calculatedEventDuration = heEvent.DateEnd.Subtract(heEvent.TimeBegin);
        if (calculatedEventDuration.Hours > 1) { icalEvent.Duration = calculatedEventDuration; }
        else { icalEvent.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1); } // default to 1 hour if event time is less

        icalEvent.Location = heEvent.Location;

        // Create a serialization context and serializer factory.
        // These will be used to build the serializer for our object.
        ISerializationContext ctx = new SerializationContext();
        ISerializerFactory factory = new DDay.iCal.Serialization.iCalendar.SerializerFactory();
        // Get a serializer for our object
        IStringSerializer serializer = factory.Build(iCal.GetType(), ctx) as IStringSerializer;

        string output = serializer.SerializeToString(iCal);
        var contentType = "text/calendar";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output);

        return File(bytes, contentType, String.Format(@"{0}.ics", heEvent.Name.Replace(" ", "_")));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your error, you don't need me to tell you, has nothing to do with Ical. It's entirely between you, your phone, and your technology budget. (Buy an SD card !)

As regards serving Icalendars, you often hear them called feeds, but clients subscribed to an Icalendar poll the calendar url regularly, requesting the whole calendar each time. To avoid lots of needless processing, you will want to persist the calendar(s) somehow so that changes propagate without regenerating the same calendar thousands of times. For this, I suggest the file system and good use of HTTP caching headers. When your calendar is modified, write it as a static file in a web facing directory. Perhaps you're already doing this. Then set sensible caching headers on your webserver and away you go.